# How many electronics can I take with me when I travel from USA to the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, cellphones, regulations

I will travel in USA net week and some of my friends asked me to buy Iphone6 for them. Maybe I have to take 5 Iphone6 with me when I am going back. Is that possible? What if I open them all and active them all? They are for friends, not for resell. Will that be possible?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-outside-the-eu

> You can bring in goods worth up to £390 duty-free.

Comment: Legally speaking, yes.  In practice, I doubt you'd have problems with a single phone, but 5 would *definitely* be pushing it.

Comment: `If you bring in any single item worth more than your allowance, you must pay duty and/or tax on the full item value, not just the value above the allowance. You also cannot group individual allowances together to bring in an item worth more than the limit.`

Comment: Also note for duty-free **the goods must be for your own use or as a gift**. If your friends will be paying you anything for the phones, then they are not gifts. So you would have to pay duty.

Comment: Learning from other people's mistakes, if you get caught and have to pay duty + a fine, I'd be quite sure that your friends won't want to pay up. Ask them to pay purchase price including sales tax, plus import duty, in cash before you leave.